# Fade in/out news headlines from API

Tags: jquery, xml, twitter-bootstrap, api

Trying to fade in and out single headlines that are being pulled from a News API.  I have five them displaying at the moment, but want them to come up one after the other on an endless loop (as if to give the appearance of breaking news headlines).

This wouldn't seem like such a hard task if it were just locally copied text, but when importing from a news API I'm not so sure.

Any help/guidance would be much appreciated.

html

```
<div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="home">
        <h3>BREAKING NEWS</h3>
        <p id="breaking_news"></p>
      </div>
```

jQuery

```
   (document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({

    url: "https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?sources=buzzfeed&apiKey=XXX",
    method: "GET",
    success: function(data) {
    processData(data);
    }
  });

  function processData(data) {
    var articleItems = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

      var title = data.articles[i].title;

      var $title = `<a href="${artUrl}"><div class="title">${title}</div ></a>`
      var artUrl = data.articles[i].url;

      $("#breaking_news").append(`${$title}`);
      $("#breaking_news").append("<br />");

      console.log(artUrl);
    }
  }
});
```